# ASP.NET confirm desde code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

He visto muchos ejemplos sobre cómo lanzar un 'confirm' de JavaScript desde el OnClick de un botón.
Lo que no encuentro es cómo:

1) Durante una Sub comprobar la información, y si es necesario, pedir confirmación al usuario
2) Abrir el 'confirm' de JavaScript
3) Si el usuario acepta, continuar la ejecución del 'code behind'. Es decir, que sea síncrono.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnConfirma() {
            document.getElementById("HiddenField1").Value = confirm("'Sí o No"); 
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Archivo (*.xlsx)" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="500px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID='btnCargar' runat='server' Text='CARGAR' OnClick="Upload" style='background-color: #A3EDC5; width: 75px; height: 26px;' />
                        <asp:Label ID="txtErrores" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>      
    </form>
</body>
```

```
    Public Sub Upload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim PATH As String
    Dim WB As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet, StY4W2 As String, dr As SqlDataReader

    If Me.FileUpload1.FileName = "" Or System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower() <> ".xlsx" Then
        txtErrores.Text = "Seleccione un archivo tipo 'xlsx'"
    Else
        txtErrores.Text = ""
        Try
            PATH = "XXXXX"
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(PATH & "\XXXXX.xlsx")
            Using fstream As New FileStream(PATH & "\XXXXX.xlsx", FileMode.Open)
                WB = New Workbook(fstream)
                Ws = WB.Worksheets("O Bank Current Week")
                StY4W2 = Ws.Cells(2, 5).Value.ToString & Right("00" & Ws.Cells(2, 6).Value.ToString, 2)
            End Using

            Dim cnxstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("hacheConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using cnn As New SqlConnection(cnxstr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand                        
                    cnn.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = cnn

                    StY4W2 = Ws.Cells(2, 5).Value.ToString & Right("00" & Ws.Cells(2, 6).Value.ToString, 2)

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) NumR FROM TAB_XXXXX WHERE FLD_Y4W2='" & StY4W2 & "'"
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dr.Read()
                    If IsDBNull(dr("NumR")) = True Then
                        Procesar()
                    Else
                        If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("fnConfirma")) Then
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "fnConfirma", "fnConfirma();", True)
                        End If

                        If HiddenField1.Value = "true" Then
                            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TAB_OBANK_EVOLUTION WHERE FLD_Y4W2='" & StY4W2 & "'"
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                            Procesar()
                        End If
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close() : dr.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Pero cuando ejecuto esto el javascript no se ejecuta hasta que toooodo el "code behind" ha acabado.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute una función de javascript en un punto concreto del code behind, y que no prosiga hasta que se responda?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a VB, pon la etiqueta correspondiente de ser así. Por otro lado, dese el onclick puedes hacer lo que quieras, lo que no entiendo es a qué te refieres con eso de 'durante una Sub', y no entiendo lo que quieres conseguir tampoco

Comment: Mejor que use parametros con su query tambien con tal que evite ataques de SQL injection.